# Checking ListObject value

Tags: c#, excel-interop, assignment-operator, listobject

I am trying to check a range within my `ListObject` to see if it contains the number 9. I keep getting a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'".

```
if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].Range[1, 1].value2 = 9)
{
    xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "YES!";
}
else 
{ 
    xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "NO!"; 
}
```

Resolved answer:

```
if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].Range[1, 1].value2 == 9)
{
    xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "YES!";
}
else 
{ 
    xlSheet.Cells[5, 5] = "NO!"; 
}
```

After reading up on operators for C#, I found out that "==" is used for comparison, while "=" is used for assignment.

Comment: Who ever down-voted this, please supply why you have down-voted this. This will help me create a better question in the future, and fix any current mistakes in the current question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].Range[1, 1].value2 == 9)
```

Your if should look like this. Make a difference between `=` and `==`

Answer (score 3):

```
if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].ListObjects["table1"].Range[1, 1].value2 == 9)
```

You are using asignment operator not the comparison operator. So Compiler thinks that you are going to assign value. and it becomes int statement instead of bool. that is why it gives error Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool. So you should use == not =